# Linspace on a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to do something like linspace, but where I specify the corners of the matrix.

For example:

```
[[-60  -2]
 [140   6]]
```

I'd like to fill out a larger matrix:

```
[[-60  -31  -2]
 [40   21    4]
 [140  73    6]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def interpolate(corners, n):
    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:n:1, 0:n:1]
    points = [[0, 0], [0, n-1], [n-1, 0], [n-1, n-1]]

    return griddata(points, corners, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')


corners = [-60, -2, 140, 6]
interpolate(corners, 3)
```

And the result isn't exactly what I expected for the middle point, but it makes sense since it's interpolating diagonally:

```
array([[-60., -31.,  -2.],
       [ 40., -27.,   2.],
       [140.,  73.,   6.]])
```